# Converting mp4 to ogg file format results in a large file

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg, mp4, ogg

I have a MP4 file of 83MB (converted from MOV of about 772MB using FFMPEG). 
For the file to be playable from all browsers from HTML5 video tag, I am converting the MP4 to OGG, again using FFMPEG command

```
ffmpeg -i object-creation.mp4 -acodec libvorbis -vcodec libtheora -q:v 5 -q:a 5 object-creation-3.ogg
```

The result of the above command is a very large OGG file of around 500 MB. I would certainly not want to upload such huge files to Amazon S3 (which I am using for storage, and distribution).

Is there something I am missing here? Is the file not compressed enough?

Is it possible to have the resultant file of somewhat manageable size like 80-100 MB without any appreciable loss in quality over what is seen in MP4 format? Why is it that even the source file is 83MB, the resultant file is too big in comparison?

Thanks
Parag

Comment: Check the frame rate of the output file.  If it is >30fps try `-vf fps=25` (or whatever you'd like the frame rate to be).

Answer (score 3):

## All things are not equal

You're comparing two different video formats: Theora video and I assume H.264 video. These were created by two different video encoders: libtheora and I assume (lib)x264 because using anything else would be a waste of time. x264 is much more efficient than libtheora, and if encoding the same input the Theora output would require a higher bitrate for an equal quality output.

## Options

### Theora

Experiment with a lower `-q:v` value. Alternatively you could declare a bitrate to target a specific output file size. [This example](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide#twopass) is for using libx264 in `ffmpeg`, but it will give you a good idea of how to do it.

### VP8

You could also try using libvpx instead. It should provide a better quality output per bitrate than libtheora, but is still not equivalent to x264. See the [FFmpeg and VPx Encoding Guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/vpxEncodingGuide).